# SQL - Joining tables in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server, and what I am trying to do is to create a trigger that will decrement QtyOnHand (from table "book") by one whenever ShipDate (from table "OrderHeader") is updated from NULL to an actual date.

As you can see from the tables below, OrderHeader and Book is not directly related to each other and I have to go through OrderDetail table from OrderHeader to get the ISBN of the book and then decrement QtyOnHand from Book table that has corresponding ISBN.

I tried to join all 3 tables in the trigger to compare OrderNo,ISBN and QtyOnHand for comparison but I am not sure if this is the right way to approach this problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

OrderHeader

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
| Name      | Type    | Null | Key |   
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
| OrderNo   | int     | NO   | PRI |
| MemberID  | char(10)| NO   |     |    
| OrderDate | date    | NO   |     |
| Address   | char(30)| NO   |     |
| ShipDate  | date    | YES  |     |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
```

OrderDetail

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
| Name      | Type    | Null | Key |   
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
| OrderNo   | int     | NO   | PRI |
| OrderLine | int     | NO   | PRI |    
| ISBN      | char(10)| NO   |     |
| Quantity  | int     | NO   |     |
| Price     | decimal | NO   |     |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
```

Book

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
| Name      | Type    | Null | Key |   
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
| ISBN      | char(10)| NO   | PRI |
| Author    | char(50)| NO   |     |    
| Title     | char(80)| NO   |     |
| QtyOnHand | int     | NO   |     |
| Price     | decimal | YES  |     |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Certainly not the right way. Your application should reduce the inventory when it marks an order as shipped.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, haven't run the query there might be some syntax error,

```
MERGE Book As Target
USING (Select OH.ISBN FROM OrderHeader OH
Inner join OrderDetail OD 
ON OH.OrderNo  = OD.OrderNo 
Where OD.ShipDate  IS NOT NULL ) AS Source
ON Source.ISBN = Target.ISBN
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET Target.QtyOnHand  = Target.QtyOnHand  + 1;
```